# How to get all dependencies for a given java class from gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, jdeps

I currently have to check several java classes if they contain some specific libraries. I am looking for the direct dependencies and transitive dependencies of the class.

Can I configure gradle to do that? I have seen, that gradle can generate me a dependency tree for the whole project and module, but unfortunately not for a specific java-class

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 task copyDoc(type: Copy) {
     from(project.configurations.getByName("runtimeClasspath"));
     into '....'
 }
```